# I want to apply cookies on domain and subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, cookies, subdomain

I have a problem and I was hoping that some of you out there might be able to help me.
I create the sub-domain correctly it all matches with the domain but when i login in the main domain it should be logged in the subdomain too, but it isn't